# How to modify the header <ul> in superfish menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I am trying to convert a html theme into drupal theme using superfish module. I can't figure out what to edit so that my menu has a different ID. So, instead of

< ul id="supermenu-1">I'd like to have < ul id ="jMenu">.
 Which files do I have to edit? Here is the code

```
    <ul id="superfish-1" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-none superfish-processed sf-js-enabled"><li class="active-trail sf-depth-1 sf-no-children" id="menu-218-1"><a class="fNiv sf-depth-1 active" href="/">Home</a></li><li class="sf-depth-1 menuparent" id="menu-443-1"><a class="fNiv sf-depth-1 menuparent" href="/?q=who-we-are">Who we are</a><ul style="float: none; width: 12em;" class="sf-hidden"><li class="sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" id="menu-444-1" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;"><a class="fNiv sf-depth-2" href="/?q=project" style="float: none; width: auto;">Project</a></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a good idea because changing that ID may break the scripted functionality of a Superfish menu but that said, here goes...

- I'm assuming you're on Drupal 7.

It's not a template that you'll be doing anything with. It is a theme function. When the Superfish menu is generated by drupal it is in response to a call to the theme_superfish() function. You can find detailed info info on it here: http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/superfish/superfish.module/function/theme_superfish/7

So with that in mind, you would want to override that funtion in your template.php file in your theme folder by copying the function to your template.php file, renaming it to YOUR_THEME_theme_superfish($variables) and changing the part at the end where it builds the menu.

If you have several Superfish menus and only want to affect one of them (ie: superfish-1), you can add a conditional to the function so that it only changes the ID of the menu when the conditions match.

Hope that works for you.